# Jquery datatable send data to server side controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am new to Jquery datatable,

I have a data table which has one editable column based on the value of another column, value gets updated.

Here is my problem: I already have a form in my page, so I couldn't use other form for datatable submit(HTML5 does not support nested forms).

I am using ASP.NET MVC.

Any idea how can I send grid data to server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ajax.data`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) option to send extra parameter to the server.

For example:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "ajax": {
    "url": "data.json",
    "data": function ( d ) {
        d.extra_search = $('#extra').val();
    }
  }
} );
```